# How to get the previous pages URL in ALL browsers using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, url, referrer

I was wondering if there is possible a JavaScript function which will return the previous page's URL in any browser. I have read previous questions and answers about:

```
document.referrer;
```

But I believe it does not work in Internet Explorer. Is there another function that I could use? I need it to be able to work in all browsers and I need to be able to access the URL to pass it to a function. Thanks

Comment: You may navigate to it using `history.back()` but you cannot access the link directly. That would be a massive security concern.

Comment: I need access to the link to be able to pass it to a function..

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make "Go Back" button then, you may use this code

```
<input type="button" onClick="window.history.go(-1);" value=" < Go Back"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may move forward and backward through the history but accessing a particular URL is not possible since that would be a pretty big security concern.

To move back or forward in the history, you may call `history.back()` and `history.forward()` respectively.

To navigate back or forward more than one step at a time, you may call `history.go()` passing in a positive or negative integer representing the direction and number of steps. Examples follow.

```
history.go(-5); // Goes five steps backward.
history.go(2); // Goes two steps forward.
```

You can also access the number of steps in the history stack using `history.length` by the way.